# Android app not loading next page after splash

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a problem running my app on some Android devices. After splash screen activity stopped running.

But in older devices, app is running without any problem.

gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.simcoder.tinder"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
```

I have 3 layouts as a responsive  layouts:

1. w360dp-port,
2. w480dp-port,
3. sw600dp

debug codes

```
> 2019-03-15 10:49:03.527 20943-20943/com.coder.t V/InputMethodManager:
> Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@2a87464 nm :
> com.coder.t ic=null 2019-03-15 10:49:03.527 20943-20943/com.coder.t
> D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0 2019-03-15 10:49:03.527
> 20943-20943/com.coder.t I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner -
> mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus 2019-03-15 10:49:03.531
> 20943-20943/com.coder.t D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed:
> fd=87 2019-03-15 10:49:03.531 20943-20943/com.coder.t
> D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=81 2019-03-15
> 10:49:03.565 20943-20967/com.coder.t D/OpenGLRenderer:
> eglDestroySurface = 0xdb88cac0, 0xc4f4a800 2019-03-15 10:49:03.578
> 20943-20943/com.coder.t
> D/ViewRootImpl@f1dbeba[secondtimeloaddigActivity]: Relayout returned:
> old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x5
> surface={valid=false 0} changed=true 2019-03-15 10:49:03.599
> 20943-20967/com.coder.t D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface =
> 0xdb88cd18, 0xc4d1d800 2019-03-15 10:49:03.610 20943-20943/com.coder.t
> D/ViewRootImpl@21d4340[AfterSplashLoadingActivity]: Relayout returned:
> old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x5
> surface={valid=false 0} changed=true 2019-03-15 10:49:03.613
> 20943-20967/com.coder.t D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface =
> 0xdb88c070, 0xc6312800 2019-03-15 10:49:03.623 20943-20943/com.coder.t
> D/ViewRootImpl@6801b67[splashActivity]: Relayout returned:
> old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x5
> surface={valid=false 0} changed=true 2019-03-15 10:49:03.799
> 20943-20943/com.coder.t
> D/ViewRootImpl@21d4340[AfterSplashLoadingActivity]:
> dispatchDetachedFromWindow 2019-03-15 10:49:03.799
> 20943-20943/com.coder.t D/InputEventReceiver: channel '5c7830
> com.coder.t/com.coder.t.AfterSplashLoadingActivity (client)' ~
> Disposing input event receiver. 2019-03-15 10:49:03.799
> 20943-20943/com.coder.t D/InputEventReceiver: channel '5c7830
> com.coder.t/com.coder.t.AfterSplashLoadingActivity (client)'
> ~NativeInputEventReceiver. 2019-03-15 10:49:03.804
> 20943-20943/com.coder.t D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed:
> fd=80 2019-03-15 10:49:03.813 20943-20943/com.coder.t
> D/ViewRootImpl@6801b67[splashActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
> 2019-03-15 10:49:03.813 20943-20943/com.coder.t D/InputEventReceiver:
> channel '2cc9bc5 com.coder.t/com.coder.t.splashActivity (client)' ~
> Disposing input event receiver. 2019-03-15 10:49:03.813
> 20943-20943/com.coder.t D/InputEventReceiver: channel '2cc9bc5
> com.coder.t/com.coder.t.splashActivity (client)'
> ~NativeInputEventReceiver. 2019-03-15 10:49:03.818
> 20943-20943/com.coder.t D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed:
> fd=61
```

Can someone explain me the issue.

Update- my firebase codes in the activity

```
public class AfterSplashLoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener2;
    private DatabaseReference usersDb,usersDb2 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_splash_loading);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user !=null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AfterSplashLoadingActivity.this, secondtimeloaddigActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

        firebaseAuthStateListener2 = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user ==null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AfterSplashLoadingActivity.this, seekersmsoremailActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };



    }




    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener2);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have made a layout for w360dp-port, w480dp-port, sw600dp devices resolution. if you run an app in another resolution device then your app won't work.

Comment: yes is that the problem ? Do i need to have layout for each resolution

Comment: No. make common layout.

Comment: Thanks, i will check if this will work with common layout

Comment: This is my debug code

Comment: common layout did not work,  same  result

Comment: Is you layout so comlicated that you need layouts for different resolutions??

Comment: had a issue with placement of elements for different screen sizes. that is why i crated separate layouts

Comment: Make a common layout. I think in your layout some high-resolution image exist, if that's the case then move that image to `nodpi` folder then run your app it will work.

Comment: Hi , i have placed the images to nodpi folder and used common layout still not working after splash has loaded.   App works on my old android device but not in my other android phones

Comment: i have found the issue, I have Fire base authentication after splash activity. for some reason app is not communicating with firebase when it run on some  of the android phones. is fire base auth is differently apply  to each android OS   ?